# Can I use a key from a dict I'm still defining?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For instance, is there a way to call `a` while defining `b` as outlined below?

```
c = dict(
    a = "foo",
    b = a + "bar"
)
```

Or can I only use:

```
c = dict()
c['a'] = "foo"
c['b'] = c['a'] + "bar"
```

Comment: You should use the second form. As far as I am concerned, there is no way of doing what you suggest

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

This should be refactored:

```
a = "foo"
c = dict(a=a, b=a+"bar")
```

You *could* do it in one line, without the temporary variable `a`, but it's not pretty:

```
c = (lambda x: dict(a=x, b=x+"bar"))("foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

No. With the first example you provided it's not possible. The seconds example is more Pythonic.

If you really want it to be in one call you will probably not have hard coded values so you could use:

```
text = "foo"
c = dict(
    a = text,
    b = text + "bar"
)
```